# Cognito Custom Message Trigger doesn't have any effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-cognito

I am trying to customize the message sent to the user pre-verification by using the custom message trigger, I verified that the data returned from the lambda is valid and the modifications are as I want them to be, however it seems that those changes are not taking any effect as I get the standard verification details to my email

I failed to find any solutions in aws docs, anyone had the same issue ?

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

// Handler will handle our request comming from the API gateway
func Handler(event events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage) (events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage, error) {

    if event.TriggerSource == "CustomMessage_SignUp" {
        event.Response.EmailMessage = "Welcome to myapp, please click the following link to verify your email, this is a custom message"
        event.Response.EmailMessage = fmt.Sprintf(`Please click the link below to verify your email address. https://apigateway.myapp.com/auth/validate?client_id=%s&user_name=%s&confirmation_code=%s`, event.CallerContext.ClientID, event.UserName, event.Request.CodeParameter)
    }

    return event, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that in the cognito panel under message customizations verification type code needs to be checked (not link), after I did that the trigger does change the message

Comment: Hey @Smail , I am facing the same issue.. didn't get where this option "type code" is on message customizations tab which you have mentioned.
can you please help me to find that ?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late answer, if can help you there is verification type and the radio button code or link ... you need to choose code

Comment: What an infuriating requirement. It shouldn't matter whether code or link is selected, as we're customizing the message that's sent anyway. Also, if the correct string isn't present in the text, it just silently fails?! What a joke. But, thank you for this answer.

Comment: Helpful related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514305/aws-cognito-custom-email-message-with-lambda-trigger-being-overwritten?rq=3#comment135148478_66393434

Answer (score 2):

It works also for verification link, but you have to use the code parameter as `{##Verify email##}` and not `{####}` in your User Pool - Message customization settings. And then also use `{##Verify email##}` keyword in your html template.