# AWS Cognito - Custom email message with Lambda trigger being overwritten

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm using a lambda function to customize confirmation emails with AWS Cognito. My lambda function seems to work fine and looks like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const sampleTemplate = `<html>
    <body>
      <div>${event.request.codeParameter}</div>
      <div>${event.userName}</div>
    </body>
  </html>`


  if (event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser") {
    event.response.emailSubject = 'Lets hope this works'
    event.response.emailMessage = sampleTemplate

    console.log(event.response) // Logs look as expected
  }

  callback(null, event);
};
```

The problem is that when the emails arrive the message body is being overwritten by the content in the User Pools > Message Customizations tab. The subject line is working fine, but the email body is being overwritten. For example, the cognito settings look like this:
[image]

And the emails look like this:
[image]

As you can see, the lambda function worked for setting the email's subject line, but not the actual content. I can't find any setting to turn off that content and it can't be left blank... Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone finding this, I was able to find the answer. When using the `CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser` event, cognito will silently throw an error if you use `event.userName` in the template. Instead use `event.request.usernameParameter` and it will work

Comment: this silent error just made me waste two days of work. Thanks for the considerable help

Answer (score 5):

If after doing everything, your custom email template doesn't show up then check the following:

- Verification type is set to "code" not "link". ( Your Pool > General settings > message customizations ) Ref: https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/521#issuecomment-358383440
- Email HTML template shouldn't exceed more than 20,000 UTF characters. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html#aws-lambda-triggers-custom-message-example
- Check this tutorial - https://medium.com/@hasnat_33856/customize-your-cognito-verification-emails-with-html-pages-using-lambda-function-e6fff7ebfb94

Comment: The setting may have moved. Mine was at Amazon Cognito > User pools > [pool name] > Messaging > Message templates > Invitation message > Edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We **MUST** include both the "{username}" and "{####}" placeholder for the custom template for `CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser` to work. We can place this ourselves in the html file or via the `event` object's values for the keys `event.request.usernameParameter` and `event.request.codeParameter` respectively.

In summary, the html file for `CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser` must include these two values:

`event.request.usernameParameter` (has value "{username}") and
`event.request.codeParameter` (has value "{####}")

Comment: Good +1, that's why my `smsMessage` was overwritten. I still have a problem that the `Invitation Email` is not resent, when i use `AdminCreateUser API` with `--message-action RESEND`.